# Getting a time difference in Java LocalDateTime and converting it to String format

Tags: java, string, time, java-8, localdate

I'm taking a time difference between two LocalDateTime values. I'm using the `Duration` for that. And now I want to convert it into `hh:mm:ss` format as a String value. I've been checking how this can be done but still no luck. Any guidance will be appreciated.

```
 LocalDateTime startTime = some value
 LocalDateTime endTime = some value
 Duration totalWaitingDuration = Duration.between(endTime, startTime);
 String waitingTime = String.valueOf(totalWaitingDuration.toHours());
```

In this, I'm getting the time difference only in hours. How can i get it in `hh:mm:ss` format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use apache commons:

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(totalWaitingDuration.toMillis(), "H:mm:ss", true)
```

Duration must not be negative.

Comment: Have you tried with totalWaitingDuration.toString() method?